# is it possible to build an app that runs in 32bit in Leopard but 32/64bit universal in Snow Leopard with XCode?

Tags: xcode, 64-bit, osx-snow-leopard, 32-bit, osx-leopard

I need to load flashplayer with webkit. but even the latest 'square' flashplayer doesn't support 64bit in Leopard by default. Unless I use the flashplayer-10.6.plugin instead.
since webkit use a pluginAgent in Snow Leopard when running in 64bit mode. it does't matter whether my app is 32bit or 64bit. but unfortunately, the pluginAgent is not available in Leopard.
i saw some build conditions on [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/300-Build_Settings/bs_build_settings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002691-SW3). but it seems there's no OS condition available.
so, i wonder is there any possibility to make it with build settings? or any other way except building two standalone versions.

thanks
xx

Comment: You might want to ask yourself why you feel the need to have a 64-bit executable ? Is there some reason why a 32-bit executable is unacceptable on Snow Leopard ?

Comment: it is not quite necessary but most builtin osx apps are 64/32bit universal. with 64bit in Snow Leopard, webkit will use the pluginAgent to load flashplayer. that mode would be more stable and i can enable GC in 64bit by build conditions.